# Optimize result list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm getting following data from my Stored procedure

```
Brand               Start     End
----------------------------------------   
Nike                0         4      
Adidas              0         5      
Nike                4         10     
Levis               0         3     
Adidas              5         8
```

I want to check if there is any range data for given start and end numbers and if there is any data with given range i want to get maximum "End" number of each brand

ex: assume that i want to check whether there is any data for gap 2 to 6
in this case;

**for NIKE:**
NIKE has ranges 0-4 and 4-10. So its within my 2-6 range (2 is in between 0-4 and 6 is in between 4-10) So i want my result as "NIKE 10"

**for ADIDAS:** ADIDAS has ranges 0-5 and 5-8. So it also within 2-6 range (2 is in between 0-5 and 6 is in between 5-8) I want it as "ADIDAS 8"

**for LEVIS:** LEVIS has one range 0-3 and 2 is in between that range. So i want it as "LEVIS 3"

i wrote a Linq query for that and i want to make sure that it's working fine.

```
var result = (from items in responce.List
              where items.Start>= 2 && items.End <= 6
              group items by items.Brand into g
              select new
              {
                 Max = g.Max(x=> x.End)
              });
```

the result should contain;

```
NIKE 10
ADIDAS 8
LEVIS 3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the question here ? Should result contain number of elements or just `Nike 10` if there are *any* Nike elements with range of 0-4 and 4-10 ?

Comment: @Fabjan actually I want to all the brands within that given range. But I want it as
NIKE - 10 
ADIDAS - 8
LEVIS - 3 

ex: NIKE has ranges "0-4" and "4-10". So I want NIKE brand with its maximum End value 10

Comment: What is `items.Start` ? What type does `responce.List` contain ?

Comment: @Fabjan responce.List has the result set from the SP with brand names and start and end ranges. items is just a variable name for Linq query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, took me a minute to understand what you were after, but all you need to do is treat each number in your range as an independent value.

That means the database range can have either the 2, the 6 or both between its values.

all you need to do is rewrite the linq to something like this:

```cs
var result = from item in list
             where (item.Start <= 2 && item.End >= 2) || (item.Start <= 6 && item.End >= 6)
             group item by item.Brand into g
             select new
             {
                 Brand = g.Key,
                 Max = g.Max(x => x.End)
              };
```

The only change being

```cs
where (item.Start <= 2 && item.End >= 2) || (item.Start <= 6 && item.End >= 6)
```

All these does is check if any range has *2* or if any range has *6* in it.

For a complete example see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/roysanchez/6bf6fac93cd37bef9bc6d4f837df181f).

***EDIT:***

Try this one, it should always show the max range for the brand, if the values specified exists inside that brand:

```cs
var result = (
                from item in list
                group item by item.Brand into g
                from subItem in g
                where (subItem.Start <= 2 && subItem.End >= 2) || (subItem.Start <= 6 && subItem.End >= 6)
                select new
                {
                    Brand = g.Key,
                    Max = g.Max(x => x.End)
                }
            ).Distinct();
```

Here's another [gist with the updated linq](https://gist.github.com/roysanchez/e54aac300d07d4b6138d8e31fc8a9b87).

Comment: Thanks for your help. your solution is actually work for given numbers (2 and 6). it gives me all the results i want. But if use 0 and 4 instead of 2 and 6 its not working. it gives 5 for ADIDAS. i want same result for every pair within the ranges. 

If i use 0 and 2 instead of 2 and 6 it gives me below result as well. :( :( 

NIKE    4
ADIDAS    5
LEVIS   3

Comment: Let me try to understand, you want to get the same results whether the values are (2,6), (0,4) or (0,2) ?

Comment: yes sir :) that's correct. because all (2,6), (0,4) or (0,2) these ranges are in their current ranges.

ex: 0 and 4 are in NIKE's first range (0-4), ADIDAS 0-5 range and for LEVIS it has 0 in its range (0-3)

i want to check their current ranges with my numbers. if my numbers can found in their any current ranges i want its maximum End number.

Comment: what i want to do here is, i need to set available start number for next range. If my current numbers are already within their ranges i need inform next available number for range. 

Ex: currently NIKE has 0-4 and 4-10 ranges. So my next range should starts with 10. (ie. 10-15). above mentioned 2 and 6 are Start and End range for a new range. But those two numbers already in other ranges. So i need to user to know that next range should start with 10.

@roy hope you have a clear idea now. it was my mistake in explaining sorry about that.  :(

Comment: it's working :) :) :) Thank you so much! You have no idea how grateful I am for your help. You saved my day

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Sneaker> sneakers = new List<Sneaker>() {
                new Sneaker() { brand = "Nike", start = 0, end = 4},
                new Sneaker() { brand = "Adidas", start = 0, end = 5},
                new Sneaker() { brand = "Nike", start = 4, end = 10},
                new Sneaker() { brand = "Levis", start = 0, end = 3},
                new Sneaker() { brand = "Adidas", start = 5, end = 8}
            };
            int start = 2;
            int end = 6;
            var groups = sneakers.GroupBy(x => x.brand).Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.end)).Select(x => x.Any(y => y.end > end) ? x.FirstOrDefault(): x.LastOrDefault())
              .Where(x => x != null).Select(x => new {brand = x.brand, end = x.end}).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it gives only the first item's End values only.

if my two numbers (2 and 6 in here) are within their brand ranges I need the maximum End number of that brand. 

ex: for 2 and 6 it should give 10 for NIKE, 8 for ADIDAS and 3 for LEVIS
same should come for if i use 0 and 4, 0 and 2, etc instead of 2 and 6. Thank you